# Heat dissipation through multiple layers of different materials

Tags: thermodynamics

Given 3 materials A, B and C, where A adjoins B, and B adjoins C.
A is exothermic.
B is a thermal insulator.
C is a thermal conductor.
Does the thermal conductivity properties of C affect how heat is dissipated from A in any way? Or can it only be affected by B?

Comment: It affects it, however not by much, unless you turn it into an insulator too.  This scenario can be thought of as electrical resistors in series.  Insulator is high resistance.  conductor is low.  `high+low ~= high` however if low was swapped for extremely high then `high+extremely high ~= extremely high`  This is for heat leaving through b and then through C.  If A has a different path for heat transfer that is much more conductive, the path through B and C may be insignificant for A anyway (resistors in parallel).

Comment: @Abel thanks for that, makes a lot of sense. If you post that as an answer I'll mark it as accepted if nothing better comes along in the next few days.